# Testing dishwasher drain hose after snaking cloggage but before putting back

Tags: dishwasher, testing

My dishwasher (Samsung DMT400RHS) stopped working (it would turn itself off 10-15 min after start) and I determined it was because the drain hose/assembly was clogged so it couldn't flush out. I took the hose connection out of the garbage disposal (the other end), tried blowing in it and I couldn't get to blow through. I also took the dishwasher out of the housing, which is why I'm asking this (bear with me).

So I took my small drain snake, cleaned it and got it to blow through. I was hoping to test it by monitoring the puddle of water in the bottom to get bubbles as I was blowing through but there were no bubbles. The stream of air I was blowing was exiting somewhere else.

Before I put the thing back in, I would like to test indeed that it is fixed. Is it possible that it is okay now even though I'm not getting air stream inside the machine because there is some valve that is closed so the blown stream is leaving somewhere else? I would prefer to get a positive test before I put it back in so I don't have to take it out again. I am also worried that I may have disconnected the hose from the machine when pulling it out and running a cycle could flood my kitchen.

How do I test this?

Comment: How is it you can't see both ends of the hose? They're usually in plain sight on the underside of the unit.

Comment: As of now I can't see the end of the hose that goes into the DW. It requires further disassembly which I would prefer to not have to do

Comment: I'd run a clean water cycle with the unit outside the cabinet bay and the hose secured in the sink or a bucket. Put down some towels under the pump area.

Comment: +1 for "just put the hose in a large bucket, check that it works, then put it all back in place".